# Hint the compiler to return by reference when using auto, without using ->

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, return-type, auto

I have a function that has the return type set to auto. If I want to return something by reference, normally I can simply hint the compiler with `-> T&`. However in my specific case I have a templated function which has different return paths defined through an if constexpr expression. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto fn(T& arg)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return;
    else
        return arg;
}
```

I want to return `arg` by reference in the second case. Is there a way to hint the compiler as to the type inside the function body?
I know that I can do std::ref(arg), but then the returned type is a reference wrapper, so if I do `auto& res = fn(arg)` it simply fails when I try to use it as an actual reference. Basically I want the vanilla behaviour one would get through `-> T&`, but for a function that can return various types, so I want to provide the hint within the function body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `decltype(auto)` instead, which evaluates to the exact type of the expression you're returning:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) fn(T& arg)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return;
    else
        return arg;
}
```

- When calling `int i; fn(i);`, the return type will be `void`.
- When calling `float f; fn(f);`, the return type will be `float&`.

[**live example on godbolt.org with `static_assert` evidence**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UdhkAZ)

Comment: Your live example provides supporting evidence, not proof

Comment: @Peter: fair, changed.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `decltype(auto)` is for. Just change your signature to

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) fn(T& arg)
```